# Optimizing code for python, values from a 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, 2d

I just wrote this bit of code and was wondering if there was any way to optimize the print out.  I attempted to use a .format() to include the total and the 'even' or 'odd'.  If I just assign the return from the function to a variable prior to calling would I be able to limit to one print statement?

Basically this code you enter a 2d array and it will return the total value.

```
def evenrow(TwoDArray):
    counter = 0
    counterTwo = 0
    lengthArray = len(TwoDArray)
    lengthList = len(TwoDArray[0])
    while counter < lengthArray:
        while counterTwo < lengthList:
            value = TwoDArray[counter][counterTwo]
            value += value
            counterTwo += 1
        counter += 1
    return value

TwoDArray = eval(input("Enter a 2D array: "))
print('Total Value: ', evenrow(TwoDArray))
if evenrow(TwoDArray) % 2 == 0:
    print('Even or Odd: Even')
else:
    print('Even or Odd: Odd')
```

Example of output:

```
Enter a 2D array: [[0,2],[1,1]]
Total Value:  4
Even or Odd: Even
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can optimize evenrow as well, via a construct like: sum(sum(row) for row in TwoDArray)

Comment: Is that the for equivalent of the nested while loop?

Comment: Yes, that's the equivalent of the nested while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! I hope you have a great time here.

As to your question - easy as pie:

```
ret = evenrow(TwoDArray)
if ret % 2 == 0:
    print('Total Value: %d\nEven or Odd: Even' % ret)
else:
    print('Total Value: %d\nEven or Odd: Odd' % ret)
```

I can even do you one better and get it down to one line using Python's equivalent of the ternary operator:

```
ret = evenrow(TwoDArray)
print('Total Value: %d\nEven or Odd: %s' % (ret, 'Odd' if ret % 2 else 'Even'))
```

You'd want to save the return value anyway. Imagine if `evenrow()` were a computationally expensive operation -- you certainly wouldn't want to run it twice.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I used your code and it came out beautiful and efficient.  I will remember that method for the future. Appreciate it a lot! (It says I have 6 minutes for the check mark, I will make sure to check it by then)

Comment: @user2909869 You're absolutely welcome. Good luck and happy coding.

Comment: @ChristianTernus Please recommend `format` method, going forward.

Comment: @thefourtheye While str.format() is the idiomatic way going forward, it is in fact MUCH slower for simple string replacement without formatting than % replacement. In this case you are right as we are only printing once, but it is still good to know about this speed difference.